# loop through an array of ids and get result in an array in CI

Tags: php

in my controller i have an associative array in the following pattern!

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 13 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 14 ) )
```

now what i want to do is there is some data on another table where these ids are referenced as foreign keys what i want to do is iterate through this array of ids and fetch data from another table on the basis of these ids! 
this will be my query

```
 $this->db->select("path");
        $this->db->from('main_data');
        $this->db->where("f_key",$id); //this is the id i want to take from array i written above
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not writing a query join, so you are only making one database call?

Comment: Search for the word "join" on this page and it will show you how: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Comment: for join also i need to iterate this array , this array is returned after a number of conditions so i can thought it would be better if i just uses this array to fetch data from the table moreover i dont need data from multiple table, just from one table so join is not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this give you enough to complete your work or do you need more?  I can't test my code if I include your codeigniter code in there, since I don't have your database.

```
<pre>
<?php
  $arrOfIds = array( array( "id" => 13 ), array( "id" => 14 ));
  foreach($arrOfIds as $row) {
    $id = $row["id"];
    echo $id . "\r\n";
    //remove the echo statement and run your queries and do whatever you need to do
  }
 ?>
</pre>
```